# If $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{\lambda}I_p)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}( 0 ,I_n)$, are they independent?

Tags: probability

Suppose both $X$ and $Y$ are multivariate normal such that $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{1}{\lambda}I_p)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}( 0 ,I_n)$, are they independent? By multiplying their densities together, I got

\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{p/2}\lambda^{-p}} \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}X^T \lambda X - \frac{1}{2} Y^T Y\right) \\[5pt]
= {} & -\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{(n+p)/2}\lambda^{-p}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} \lambda^{-1} I_p & 0 \\ 0 & I_p \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y\end{bmatrix}\right)
\end{align}

Can I conclude that $X$ and $Y$ are independent? My concern is that the thing I got might not be their joint distribution at all. In fact, to argue that their joint distribution is indeed the product of marginal, I have to assume they are independent in the first place?

Comment: Your concern is correct: there is no reason why $X$ and $Y$ should be independent.

Comment: Giving the distributions of X and Y gives no indication about the dependence of X and Y. Sorry but what is your source on (stochastic) independence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generally tell from the distributions of two variables $X$ and $Y$ whether or not they're independent. Let $X$ and $Y$ be Bernouilli of parameter $\frac 1 2$. Are they independent? Well, they could be. But we could also have $X=Y$.

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have those distributions you cannot tell whether they are independent without further information.

But if the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is the one you have given, then they are independent.